# Characteristic polynomial of u is irreducible iff u has not stable subspace not trivial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ be an endomorphism of E, a finite dimensional vector space.

I woudl like to show that **if u has not stable subspace not trivial then the characteristic polynomial $\chi_u$ of $u$ is irreducible**.

I don't know how to prove that. 
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Suppose $\chi_u = pq$ with $\mathrm{deg} p, \mathrm{deg}q > 0$. Prove that $\mathrm{im}\,p(u)$ is an invariant subspace of $u$.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I know that $Im~p(u)$ is an invariant subspace of $u$ but why $Im~p(u)$ is not equal to $E$ ?